# c++ memory initialization for passed arguments

Tags: c++

I am writng a c++ program. I am parsing a file and initializing a structure. I have an array to initialize but I have to read the size of the array from the file. I want the array length read and array initialization in one function. If I pass the array pointer to another function and do a new, when the function returns, the pointer is destroyed, and I cannot see the initialized values. Is this expected or am I missing something. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You should show your code to get some answer

Comment: Actually besides missing code demonstrating your problem it's hard to understand particularly the middle part. You do a operator `new` call and then what?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: And he gets access denied exception!

Answer (score 7):

You overcome this by forgetting everything about manual arrays, raw pointer passing* and `new`. This is C++, not 1991. So, a typical solution could be this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>
#include <istream>

std::vector<uint32_t> read_data(std::istream & is)
{
  uint32_t len;
  is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof(uint32_t));

  std::vector<uint32_t> result(len);
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i != len; ++i)
  {
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&result[i]), sizeof(uint32_t));
  }

  return result;
}
```

(In high-quality code, the `read` commands would be surrounded by a conditional and errors would be handled, possibly by throwing an exception.)

Later:

```
#include "int_reader.hpp"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream infile("thedata.bin", std::ios::binary);
  std::vector<uint32_t> data = read_data(infile);

  std::cout << "We read " << data.size() << " integers.\n";
}
```

<sub>*) The only raw pointer that has a place in general-purpose C++ is a `char*` when used for I/O operations, as demonstrated by this code. C++ defined `char` to be the machine's fundamental data unit type, and I/O happens in units of `char`.</sub>

Comment: well I agree with you, but I am really new to c++, have been working in C and embedded systems for 8 years now, I would need some time to overcome the habit of writing everything by own hand :)

Comment: @Saba: You definitely want to forget almost everything about C if you want to be eloquent in C++ :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is no array pointer before you call `new`. So there's no way you could pass it to a function.

Likely what you're doing is passing the uninitialized, garbage value of the array pointer to a function. The function overwrites its copy of that garbage value with the correct pointer returned from `new`, but then the original function never sees that pointer.

You need to pass the function a pointer to the pointer. Then when it calls `new`, it can use the pointer to the pointer to update the caller's pointer. Like this:

```
void SomeFunction(void **SomePointer)
{
    (*SomePointer) = malloc(1024);
}


void *MyPointer;
SomeFunction(&MyPointer);
```

Comment: And I agree with Kerrek, this is the C way to do things. The C++ way is much nicer.

Comment: Except you can't dereference a `void*` or are you missing a star for `void**` ?

Comment: I fixed it about two seconds after I posted it. Yet another reason not to write code like this. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a pointer to a pointer in order to have a function allocate it for you

```
void allocateArrayOfT(T** objArray, size_t len) {
    *objArray = new T[len];
}
```

You can call:

```
T* arrayPtr;
allocateArrayOfT(&arrayPtr, len);
```